# Meteor.js: How are HTML templates served?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I read that Meteor doesn't do any server side processing of view templates. Does this mean that HTML is served as-is to the client, with AJAX requests to populate dynamic parts of the page?

How does this compare to server side template processing in terms of serving the same dynamic-content-rich page to many users (100s of thousands)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of broad, and I don't think this is the place for such comparisons, but I'll try to get you started regarding Meteor's approach:

Meteor used to be bundled with a view layer called **Blaze**. It is still the official view layer, but it appears that the next version will be based on React.js. Anyway, Meteor is more loosely coupled from Blaze now and you can choose any view layer, with Blaze, **React** and **Angular** being officially supported.

All of the above are templates/components that are **compiled to JavaScript** and rendered on the client, based on state/data available locally.

This data is usually obtained via a **pub/sub** mechanism (using a local cache that mimics the *MongoDB* interface, called *MiniMongo*) and mutated via async RPC mechanism called Meteor Methods.

The Meteor servers monitor the database for changes by looking at a change stream called OpLog.

When a client requests data (via a subscription), the server fetches the initial data and monitors for changes. If an OpLog changes matches a subscription's criteria, an update is sent to the client.

The notion of Reactive Computations is used throughout the framework, where some data sources can be invalidated and re-evaluate functions that depend on them.

Combined with a client-side router you often get what is commonly referred to as a SPA (single page application).

The state of the application (route + data + local state) normally dictates what views are rendered on the screen.

Currently, Meteor bundles the views and other code during the build process and sends the bundle to the client, which then has all of the code that it needs to render all of the views and fetch the required data.

A more modular approach is being investigated by the community (via alternative build methods) and is expected in the upcoming version 1.3 of Meteor.

The data transport mechanism is the Meteor **DDP** (distributed data protocol), which uses a **WebSocket** when possible to transfer data back and forth between the client and the server, so no need for AJAX/Comet calls for each state mutation.

I think that the spectrum of alternative implementations is too broad to discuss in a SO answer. It really depends on how "reactive" or "real time" you want your app to be.

The server capacity greatly depends on your implementation:

- the amount of data each user needs and the frequency in which this data changes
- the way you construct your queries (getting the data you need and doing so efficiently)
- the way you partition your code
- the hardware, of course

It can range from hundreds to 10's of thousands of connected users per server. No real way of providing a generic answer here.

An interesting [guide](http://guide.meteor.com/) is being created to demonstrate best practices using Meteor.

Comment: Thank you, I see I'll have to increase my resolution a bit too work with this. Great answer